# Proving a modified u-substitution formula.

Tags: calculus

$f$, $g'$ are continuous and $g$ is one-one. I need to prove that $$\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(u)(g^{-1})'(u)du=\int_a^bf(g(x))dx.$$
Clearly this is related to the standard formula, and looks even more related if I just write $$\int_a^bf(g(x))dx=\int_a^bf(g(x))\cdot \frac 1 {g'(x)}\cdot g'(x)dx.$$
But I don't see how I can apply the original proof or formula to this case. Since $g$ is one-one I can go back to Riemann sums and prove it this way without too much trouble, but I'd like to know if there is a shorter (rigorous) way if doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we differentiate $g(g^{-1}(x))=x$, we get $(g^{-1})'(x)=\frac1{g'(g^{-1}(x))}$

The integral is thus equal to $$\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}\frac{f(u)}{g'(g^{-1}(u))}du$$

Now put $u=g(x)$ and $du=g'(x)dx$. The integral becomes

$$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{f(g(x))}{g'(x)}g'(x)dx$$

$$=\int_{a}^{b}f(g(x))dx$$